# Question about e-TeX in TL

Tags: texlive, e-tex

In TeX Live 2014 `man etex` reads:

> BUGS
>          This version of e-TeX implements a number of optional extensions.  In fact, many of these extensions conflict to a greater or lesser
>          extent with the definition of e-TeX.  When such extensions are enabled, the banner printed when e-TeX starts is changed to print  e-
>          TeXk instead of e-TeX.

I have some questions:

1. etex never shows e-TeX or e-TeXk banners (only pdfTeX) - is the manual incorrect?
2. Is there any *pure* e-TeX executable (not a symbolic link to pdftex) - at least the authors of e-TeX themselves use it, don't they?
3. What should be configured so that the same extensions which are disabled for `tex` will be also disabled for `etex` (considering that we cannot use `-progname`)?

Comment: Why do you need a 'pure' e-TeX? pdfTeX with just the e-TeX format loaded is identical in functionality to a stand-alone version (at least if we assume you don't try to use any pdfTeX primitives).

Comment: In terms of the NTS themselves, I think that's just Peter Breitenlohner and presumably only he can say what he does!

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't mean it literally - I just wonder why it's not out there. Peter Breitenlohner does not take responsibility for pdfTeX, does he?

Comment: BTW, `texdoc etex` doesn't seem to have any of that in: where are you getting the text from?

Comment: @JosephWright: `man etex`, i.e. `texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/etex.1`

Answer (score 10):

pdfTeX has been the standard engine for TeX Live (and MiKTeX) for some years. pdfTeX can be run without the extensions enabled as a (more-or-less) drop-in replacement for TeX90 or with the extensions enabled as a drop-in replacement for e-TeX. With a document that uses TeX90 and e-TeX primitives, pdfTeX will produce identical output to a 'real' `etex` binary (it passes the eTRIP tests). As such, there is no need for the extra effort of maintaining separate binaries (likely to be error prone). Note that `tex` does run Knuth's TeX and does *not* use the pdfTeX binary.

There are of course sources available for e-TeX alone (as a `.ch` file against `tex.web`) and with a suitable build set up this can be made into a binary. Peter Breitenlohner is active in working on TeX Live (see for example the change log for http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/) and thus certainly is in a position to build `etex` as a stand-alone binary within the TeX Live architecture: only he can say whether he does that.

Comment: If it passes eTRIP, where does the BUGS section in the manual come from? (including "This version of e-TeX fails to trap arithmetic overflow..." part) Also, what about points 1) and 3)? I'll try to build etex myself. Someone can share a recipe?

Comment: On point (1), in a current TL `etex` is just running `pdftex` in the correct set up so the banner is unsurprising.

Comment: On (3) I don't know what you mean: the extensions are disabled for `tex` (or rather with `pdftex -ini` or similar) but are enabled with `pdftex -ini -etex` or similar. I'm not sure what else you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is the recipe that works for TL packaged with Debian 8:

```
sudo apt-get install libkpathsea-dev
mkdir mydir && cd mydir
rsync -a --delete --exclude=.svn --exclude=Work tug.org::tldevsrc/Build/source/ .
mkdir Work && cd Work
../configure --disable-all-pkgs --enable-shared --with-system-kpathsea --disable-native-texlive-build
make
cd texk/web2c/
make etex
strip etex
cp etex /usr/local/bin/
<build new format>
```

As for point (3) in the question, add this to local texmf.cnf:

```
shell_escape.etex = f
parse_first_line.etex = f
```